# show that $\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{\frac{1+\tanh x}{1-\tanh x}}=\frac{1}{2}e^{\frac{x}{2}}$

Tags: calculus

What I did is to express what is inside the square root in terms of exponentials with the hope of getting $e^x$ so that when I take the square root, I have $e^{\frac{x}{2}}$ whose derivative is $\frac{1}{2}e^{\frac{x}{2}}$

But I get $e^{2x}$, when I take the square root, I am left with $e^x$

$\frac{1+\tanh x}{1-\tanh x}=\frac{1+\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}}{1-\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}}$

$=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}+e^x-e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}\times \frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}-e^x+e^{-x}}$

$=\frac{e^x}{e^{-x}}$

$=e^{2x}$

Comment: So, you have $e^x\neq e^{2x}$ for $x\neq 0$. What's the problem ?

Comment: @mamotebang You are correct, the proposed formula is wrong and the derivative is in fact $e^x$.

Comment: $\sqrt{\frac{1+\tanh x}{1-\tanh x}}=e^x$

Answer (score 1):

You are correct: $\frac{1+\tanh x}{1-\tanh x}=e^{2x}$. It follows:

$$\sqrt{\frac{1+\tanh x}{1-\tanh x}}=e^x.$$